# Using collision groups with a large amount of similar objects - COCOS 2d v3 (Chipmunk)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk, spritebuilder

I have had a good look at other similar questions here but cant seem to find one that answers my question. The answer may be simple in which case please excuse my ignorance..

I have a game with a large amount of balls (over 100). These are created dynamically depending on the amount I want. These balls are physics objects which must collide with each other, which they do by default (no collision group assigned). I also have a container in the game which the balls should not collide with but which i use to detect collision callbacks.

The problem comes when i try to assign groups to the balls and the container to prevent the collision with the container. If i assign the same collision group to all the balls:

```
// This is looped through and applied to all the 100+ balls
ball.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"ball";
```

and to the container:

```
container.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"ball";
```

then the balls will not collide with the container but they also do not collide with each other.

How would i go about making all the balls collide with each other but not with the container whilst still being able to get the collision callback from the balls intersecting the container? Do i need to apply unique group or category names to each of the balls?

Comment: groups make objects not collide with other objects in the same group, this works as documented/expected.

instead use collision category and masks to filter out collisions. see the cocos2d developer guide: https://www.makeschool.com/docs/?source=mgwu#!/cocos2d/1.3/physics/editing-body-properties